# How do you solve inequalities with quadratics on the denominator?

Tags: inequality

Q: $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}>0$

How would you solve this without graphing it?

I tried using cases but it didn't really work because the X's all cancel out or multiply with the zero. I am very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrangement gives you:
$$\frac{1-2x}{x(1-x)} > 0$$

As long as the RHS is zero you can multiply the LHS by a quantity guaranteed to be non-negative, without changing the sign of the inequality. A convenient such expression is the square of the denominator, $x^2(1-x)^2$, which is always non-negative for real $x$.

You end up with $x(1-x)(1-2x)>0$ or $x(x-1)(2x-1)>0$.

A quick sketch of the cubic shows the required solution set to be:

$0<x<\frac 12$ or $x>1$